# Update JAR libraries under Java\jre7\lib\security

Tags: java, jce

I have an application which uses unlimited JCE API. In order to get it working I had to copy the **US_export_policy.jar** and **local_policy.ja**r under the Java\jre7\lib\security. Unfortunately on some machines I don't have the rights to overwrite the JRE files. Is it possible to override the default libs passing them as JVM boot parameter ? (bootclasspath for example) or even Programmatically ?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried with the "-classpath" parameter?

Comment: Have a look at this. It may help you http://blog.eyallupu.com/2012/11/how-to-overriding-java-security.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a Programmatic solution, the following one will work:

```
try { 
Field field = Class.forName("javax.crypto.JceSecurity").
getDeclaredField("isRestricted");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(null, java.lang.Boolean.FALSE); 
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

regards